# MySQL Issue: Less than 80% of the query cache is being utilized

Tags: mysql, query-cache

This is the screenshot of issue I get from phpMyAdmin advisor

[image]

Followings are setting for query cache in `my.cnf`

```
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 64M
```

What is wrong in the above setting?

Comment: a) This is not a programming question and better fits on dba.stackexchange.com b) Did you read (and understand) the first issue in your list? c) "this setting *might* be too low" indicates that it *might* be to low, not that it *is*. (It is actually way to high, although you will probably, depending on how much you use the server, not see much of an effect in any case).

Comment: but developer should know how to set up mysql server.

Comment: And a developer should know how to use a language, e.g. the english language, yet you would not ask on stackoverflow how to use a specific english word, but you would go to [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Similarly, if your pc (that you need to develop your software) has hardware problems. And if you have a question that asks about how to administrate a server, even if it is useful to a developer, it belongs at the Database Administration Stackexchange. You can request a move to there, or simply delete your question here and ask there again.